# How to modify my mainpage to let google show subpages?

Tags: search

If you search usps on google, you can see there is a list of subpages like 
Ship A Package
Postage Calculator
Find A Store
Shop USPS
Click N' Ship
Service Updates

How can I modify my homepage or add any tag to show this on google for my website?

Answer (score 0):

Google calls those results [Sitelinks](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en). Google decides which links are Sitelinks:

> We only show sitelinks for results when we think they'll be useful to the user. 
>   [..]
>   At the moment, sitelinks are automated.
>   [..]
>   We only show sitelinks for results when we think they'll be useful to the user.
>   [..]
>   There are best practices you can follow, however, to improve the quality of your 
>   sitelinks. For example, for your site's internal links, make sure you use anchor text 
>   and alt text that's informative, compact, and avoids repetition.

Google doesn't elaborate about those best practices. But I would recommend to structure your html5 properly and use such a thing like `<nav>` to help Google making the right
decisions.

You can decide which of Google's decisions are wrong:

> If you think that a sitelink URL is inappropriate or incorrect, you can demote it.

**Demote a sitelink URL:**

1. On the Webmaster Tools Home page, click the site you want.
2. Under Search Appearance, click Sitelinks.
3. In the For this search result box, complete the URL for which you don't want a 
   specific sitelink URL to appear. (How to find the right URL.)
4. In the Demote this sitelink URL box, complete the URL of the sitelink you want to 
   demote.